# How do I get associations working right with ChartKick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I can't seem to get ChartKick configured properly.

What I am trying to do is to create a graph of the user's stock portfolio. The `portfolio` is a model, which has_many `PortStocks` each of which have a `current_value`. Each `PortStock` belongs to a `Stock`.

My models look like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: portfolios
#
#  id                   :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  user_id              :integer
#  current_dollar_value :float            default(0.0)
#  dollar_change        :float            default(0.0)
#

class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :port_stocks
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: port_stocks
#
#  id             :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  portfolio_id   :integer
#  stock_id       :integer
#  volume         :integer
#

class PortStock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolio
  belongs_to :stock
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: stocks
#
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  ticker     :string
#  name       :string
#  price      :float
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :port_stocks
end
```

I tried the following:

`<%= pie_chart @portfolio.port_stocks.group(:current_value).count %>`

But that produced this pie chart:

[image: Pie-Chart-With-No-Labels]

So when I hover, it shows me the `current_value` which is good but it also shows me `: 1` which is weird. I want it to show me the name of each `stock`, which can be accessed as `port_stocks.stock.name` along with `port_stocks.current_value` for that `port_stock` that the `stock` belongs to.

**Edit 1**

So I tried this:

`<%= pie_chart @portfolio.port_stocks.joins(:stock).group("stocks.ticker").sum(:current_value) %>`

That produces this:

[image: Pie-Chart-With-Names-Values-But-No-Formatting]

That seems to work, but I would like to be able to format the `current_value` as a currency (i.e. using `number_to_currency(current_value)`).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the correct way to do what I want:

`<%= pie_chart @portfolio.port_stocks.joins(:stock).group("stocks.ticker").sum(:current_value), prefix: "$", thousands: "," %>`

That produces this:

[image: pie-chart-with-names-and-values]